# How to reload an embedded tweet?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I looked up other answers here on SO and the proposed solution of running:

```
twttr.widgets.load();
```

doesn't work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqdd25xf/1/

The tweets in question are embedded using the standard embed code, for example:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">On this day in 1996, the final episode of The Fresh Prince aired on TV. <a href="http://t.co/nYN5PJQUbJ">pic.twitter.com/nYN5PJQUbJ</a></p>&mdash; Will Smith (@WilII_Smith) <a href="https://twitter.com/WilII_Smith/status/601025109881663488">May 20, 2015</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The reason why I want to reload them is because on IOS (iPhone) when you go from portrait to landscape mode the tweet remains in portrait size. Anyway I figured refreshing the tweet would give it the proper size upon portrait to landscape change so that it fills up the width of the screen.

Comment: The original element has been replaced. So using `load` won't work here.

Comment: Take a look at the twitter events. You can hook the orientation event to this to restyle the tweets. https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

Comment: @Mouser can you please provide an example? I read that doc page but still have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script on the page that get the tweet ID and recreate it on window change :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $.getScript('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function(){ 
        var k = 0;
        var tweet = document.getElementById('twitter-widget-'+k);
        var tweetParent, tweetID, tweetNext;
        while(tweet) {
            tweetParent = tweet.parentNode;
            tweetID = tweet.dataset.tweetId;
            $(tweet).remove();
            tweetNext = $(tweet).next();
            if (tweetNext.prop("tagName") == 'SCRIPT') tweetNext.remove();
            twttr.widgets.createTweet(
              tweetID,
              tweetParent
            );
            k++;
            tweet = document.getElementById('twitter-widget-'+k);
        }
    }); 
})
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4e43huj/)